# Change graphics API at runtime (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to use two different AR algorithms together (ARCore and EasyAR). ARCore currently only supports a small list of devices, so we want EasyAR to take over when ARCore is insufficient.

Problem is, EasyAR requires OpenGL ES2, and ARCore requires OpenGL ES3. I've written code that checks the presence of ARCore on the device, and then navigates to a scene that uses the appropriate technology. I've also implemented unity's *PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs()*, but this doesn't work on deploy, only in Unity's editor. Now I'm looking for an alternative that actually does work.

The code needs to run on android and on IOS.

```
public IEnumerator CheckCompatibility()
{
    AsyncTask<ApkAvailabilityStatus> checkTask = Session.CheckApkAvailability();
    CustomYieldInstruction customYield = checkTask.WaitForCompletion();
    yield return customYield;
    ApkAvailabilityStatus result = checkTask.Result;
    switch (result)
    {
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.SupportedApkTooOld:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Supported apk too old");
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.SupportedInstalled:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Supported and installed");
            GraphicsDeviceType[] easyAPI = { GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES2, GraphicsDeviceType.Vulkan };

            SceneManager.LoadScene("ARCoreImageTracker");
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.SupportedNotInstalled:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Supported, not installed, requesting installation");
            Session.RequestApkInstallation(false);
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.UnknownChecking:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Unknown Checking");
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.UnknownError:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Unknown Error");
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.UnknownTimedOut:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Unknown Timed out");
            break;
        case ApkAvailabilityStatus.UnsupportedDeviceNotCapable:
            _ShowAndroidToastMessage("Unsupported Device Not Capable");
            GraphicsDeviceType[] coreAPI = { GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES2 };
            PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs(BuildTarget.Android, coreAPI);
            SceneManager.LoadScene("EasyARImageTracker");
            break;
    }
}
```

Currently, I get a list of errors that says that *"The name 'PlayerSettings' does not exist in the current context"*. Any alternatives I could try?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs doesn't work at runtime.
It is only for UnityEditor.
I think you should build separately for the ARCore and EasyAR.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not an option for me. The question was specifically if there was an alternative that actually did work.